# Find the id of the object with the higher item, but below a limit

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sorting

I have an array of javascript object, the object is as this:

```
smil
.____.update (object)
|    |...
|
|____.stream (array)
|    |...
|
|____.playlist (array of object)
    |____.name (string)
    |____.scheduled
    |____...
```

Scheduled is a date, I have made a function to get it in the form of a Date object.

Now, I need to find the id of the object in smil.playlist which is in the past (inferior to a new Date object) and the closer to it.

In a previous version, I was using filter, sort and pop to get the object, but following change in the structure of the app, I now need the id of it.

old code:

```
function get_last_playlist(smilp){
    //get current date
    time = new Date();
    //Delete all of playlist which are in the future
    smilp.filter(function(element) {
        return time.getTime() > gettime(element.scheduled).getTime();
    });
    //Sort by close to current time (higher scheduled)
    smilp.sort(function(a, b) {
        return gettime(a.scheduled) - gettime(b.scheduled);
    });
    //return the first in the array
    return smil.pop();
}
```

Is there a way to return the id of the object in smilp.playlist, or do I need to rewrite a large part of the app again?

Comment: By id, do you mean the index in the array, or do you mean an "id" property on the object?

Comment: The index in the array, there is no id property in the object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this :

```
function getclosest(closest, element, index, array){
  if((time.getTime()-gettime(element.scheduled).getTime()) < (time.getTime()-gettime(closest.scheduled).getTime()) ) 
  return index;
  else
  return closest;  
}

smil.reduce(getclosest);
```